# Is there contradiction in the sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Based on what I have read, the Jaccard index is calculated by (intersection/union). [Formula for Jaccard index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj9hM.png)

And it seems that for binary cases, the sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score should be equivalent to the Jaccard index. However, I am confused about the results I am getting when I use this function. For example:

```
from sklearn import metrics

y=np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1])
y2=np.array([1,1,0,0,1,1])

metrics.accuracy_score(y,y2)
```

This should result in a Jaccard index of 4/(6+6-4)=0.5, correct?
However, the result of the last line of code is 0.67, which apparently is based on a similar/total calculation. Am I misinterpreting the Jaccard index formula?

Comment: @taha, OP is talking about binary cases, and per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), *In binary and multiclass classification, this function is equal to the jaccard_score function.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1d arrays are being treated as 6 samples, and the formula for Jaccard index is *for each sample*, as you can see better in the formula from [the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#jaccard-similarity-score), not across all samples.  (The multiclass and multilabel examples may help clear this up.)

In the case of binary classification, the predicted labels are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, 0 or 1; so the intersection has size 1 for correct predictions and 0 otherwise, while the union has size 1 for correct prediction and 2 otherwise, and so the Jaccard index for each sample is either 1 or 0.  This is then averaged across all samples ("...computes the average of Jaccard similarity coefficients..." from the User Guide), which is the same as accuracy.

Comment: I see. Though, does this not differ from the actual definition of the Jaccard index? Typically, it is based on the intersection and union of the combined samples, rather than averaging each sample. What library would I have to use to find the index based on all the samples?

Comment: The definition of Jaccard index is for measuring similarity of samples, subsets of some universal set.  To apply that to ground-truth and predictions of a model on a fixed sample would seem to take a little contortion; what are the sets A and B?  However, if you'd like, you can define a custom metric in sklearn without much trouble.  With your example as a guide for how you want to define it, it's a monotonic transformation of the ordinary accuracy score: #correct/(2*n-#correct) vs #correct/n: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%2F%282-x%29+and+x+for+x+from+0+to+1